# display specific value from combobox as default in ExtJs 2.3

Tags: extjs, combobox, extjs2

i have a combo box with few data but i want to display it's specific value as default value in drop down. I am using ext 2.3

Answer (score 1):

To do this, there is an event called `beforeRender`. Create an event listener, and in that event, search for your default value and select it.